# How do I go about using derivatives to determine a roughly rectangular figure in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

As of now I have determined that I might need the top and side oriented derivatives to determine the edges of a card (roughly rectangular figure).

```
def compute_derivative(image:np.array):
    gradients = []
    for row in image:
        gradients.append((row-np.roll(row, 1))[1:])
    return np.array(gradients)

image=cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg')
left_oriented_grad = compute_derivative(image=image)
top_oriented_grad = compute_derivative(image=image.T)

all_grad = left_oriented_grad + top_oriented_grad
cv2.threshold(all_grad, ??some value??)
```

the above prototype is what I have so far to determine the shape of the card, where do I go from here?

[image: picture from the comments]

Comment: pictures please.

Comment: https://imgur.com/2WqlOYI

Comment: you spoke of a "color gradient". what is your concept of a "color gradient"? does it exist in this picture? if so, please point it out.

Comment: oh, *please* do not call this a "color gradient". "color gradient" is evocative of different colors fading into each other, like in photo editing. your terminology will only mislead experts. you're talking about a spatial derivative. I've revised your question. you should look up what "sobel" and other filters are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Appreciate the quick response!